# Radio button not being displayed

Tags: model-view-controller

I`m having the following code, however, I can see that the radio button isn`t being diplayed.  Only the label is being displayed.  what is wrong with the code?

```
 <%Html.RadioButton("Role", Role.User, true);%><%=Role.User%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("Role", Role.User, true);%><%=Role.User%>
```

Comment: <%=Html.RadioButton("Role", Role.User, true)%><%=Role.User%> , just to remove another error that crops in.